# Traffic Flow regarding Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm an undergrad student in the Philippines and were currently using Anylogic Software for our thesis. May I ask how to put a chart/time plot that consists the traffic flow (vehicle per hour) so that we can justify that our study area is congested? Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: Hi Neil, and welcome to SOF, please always add details about your model and as far as possible what you have tried yourself and where you are struggling. Check here for more detail and examples -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The are a number of options you can use but the simplest option is to count the total number of cars in the system.

For this simply add a Road Network Descriptor and select the road network you want it to represent

[image]

Then you add a time plot, and set the value that needs to be plotted as `roadNetworkDescriptor.size()` and set the update time to hour

[image]

[image]